# SQL Alphanumeric Sort on VARCHAR Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, alphanumeric

I'm dealing with alpha numeric column values that need to be sorted by letters and then by numbers.

Example of data:

- a1
- a10
- a11
- ab2
- ab21
- ab22
- a1a
- a1b

Needs to be sorted as follows:

- a1
- a1a
- a1b
- a2
- a3
- ab1
- ab2
- ab3
- ...

Need advice on how to sort this in SQL.

Thanks.

Comment: is the string format consistent? also what is the dbms being used?

Comment: Not exactly, numeric portion is preceded by 1-3 letters.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: is this a VARCHAR field?   Is it not working with a regular `ORDER BY` clause?  IF not, what's the collation?

Comment: It is a VARCHAR field, however you end up getting 1, 10, 11, 2, 20, 21 instead of 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Using MS SQL for this

Answer (score 1):

The below may work for alphanumerics. However be warned that the behaviour is undefined for non alphanumeric values.

```
WITH A (A, N) AS (
    SELECT A, 3 + LEN(A) FROM (
        SELECT 'a1'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a10'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a11'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ab2'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ab21'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ab22'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a1a'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a1b'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a1'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a1a'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a1b'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a2'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a3'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a9'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ab1'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ab2'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ab3'
    ) T (A)
), B (A, N, I, C, D, X) AS (
    SELECT A, N, 3, CAST(SUBSTRING(A, 1, 1) AS VARCHAR(255)), CAST(SUBSTRING(A, 2, 1) AS VARCHAR(255)), CAST('' AS VARCHAR(255)) FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A, N, I + 1, D, CAST(SUBSTRING(A, I, 1) AS VARCHAR(255)), CASE WHEN ASCII(C) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 AND ASCII(D) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN CAST(X + CHAR(10 + ASCII(D)) AS VARCHAR(255)) WHEN 58 > ASCII(C) THEN CAST(X + C AS VARCHAR(255)) ELSE CAST(X + CHAR(3 + ASCII(C)) AS VARCHAR(255)) END FROM B WHERE I <= N
)
SELECT A FROM B WHERE I = N
ORDER BY X COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

The code currently sorts in a Case Sensitive manner, but may be tweaked to do a case insensitive sort as well, for example by using

```
ORDER BY UPPER(X) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

or

```
ORDER BY LOWER(X) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried?

```
SELECT column_x
FROM table_name x
ORDER BY x.column_name ASC|DESC, x.column_name ASC|DESC;
```